# QTreeWidget with multiple columns limits number of child items

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtreewidget

Could anyone help me understand the following behaviour?  If I run this PyQt script I can generate a simple window with a QTreeView with multiple child items:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt4.QtCore import QStringList

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

win = QWidget()
win.resize(320, 240)
win.setWindowTitle("Hello, Overflowers!")

treeWidget = QTreeWidget()
treeWidget.setColumnCount(1)

def addChildWidgets(parent, depth=1):
    child = QTreeWidgetItem(parent, QStringList([repr(depth)]*(depth+1)))
    if (depth<12):
        addChildWidgets(child, depth+1)
    return child

item = QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget, QStringList(["root"]))
addChildWidgets(item)    

treeWidget.insertTopLevelItems(0, [item])

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(treeWidget)

win.setLayout(layout)
win.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get the children I expect:

[image: 1 column]

However, if I change the column count,

```
treeWidget.setColumnCount(10)
```

I now get my children clipped after 6 levels

[image]

Many thanks!

Phil

Comment: There appears to be nothing wrong with your code here.  When I run this code with 10 columns in the tree widget, I get all 12 levels in the tree - BUT the displayed width of your first column is only wide enough to display the first 4 levels of the tree, if you manually widen that column (you may even have to manually increase the size of the dialog as well) you can see all 12.

Comment: Indeed!  I was getting confused by the fact that I wasn't getting an expand icon for the last child.  Thanks!